# Show that $\int_{E_n} f d \mu \to \int f d \mu$, when $n \to \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable. Consider
$$E_n = \left\{x \in \Omega : |f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{n} \right\}, n \geq 1.$$
I have shown that $\mu(E_n) < \infty$, for all $n \geq 1$. However, I can't proof what is being asked using this first result.

Comment: Can you clarify the definition of the set $E_n$? Do you mean $E_n = \{x \in \Omega: |f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$?

Comment: Sure, I'm going to edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first suppose $f\geqslant 0$ a.e.
$$ \int_{E_n}fd\mu=\int_{\Omega} f\chi_{E_n}d\mu $$
But $f\chi_{E_n}\leqslant f\chi_{E_{n+1}}$ a.e because $f\geqslant 0$ a.e and $|f\chi_{E_n}|\leqslant f$ which is integrable. Using the monotone convergence theorem, we have
$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{E_n}fd\mu=\int_{\Omega}fd\mu $$
Now in the general case, let $f^+=\max(0,f)$ and $f^-=\max(0,-f)$, then $f^+,f^-\geqslant 0$ a.e, $f^+-f^-=f$ a.e and $|f^+|,|f^-|\leqslant|f|$ a.e so that $f^+$ and $f^-$ are integrable. Using what said above, we have
$$ \int_{E_n}fd\mu=\int_{E_n}f^+d\mu-\int_{E_n}f^-d\mu \underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow }\int_{\Omega}f^+d\mu-\int_{\Omega}f^-d\mu=\int_{\Omega}fd\mu $$

Comment: Using Dominated Convergence Theorem is more direct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E=\{x\in\Omega\mid f(x)\neq0\}$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
define $E_{n}=\{x\in\Omega\mid|f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{n}\}$. Observe that
$1_{E_{n}}\rightarrow1_{E}$ pointwisely, so $f1_{E_{n}}\rightarrow f1_{E}$
pointwisely too. Note that $|f1_{E_{n}}|\leq|f|$ and $|f|$ is integrable.
By dominated convergence theorem, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n}\int_{E_{n}}f\,d\mu & = & \lim_{n}\int f1_{E_{n}}\,d\mu\\
 & = & \int f1_{E}\,d\mu\\
 & = & \int f\,d\mu.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: We do not need the fact that $\mu(E_n)<\infty$.